# How do I know what plan the user chose with Stripe's Checkout.js?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, checkout

I am listing all our plans with a subscribe button as follows (django template syntax):

```
  {% for plan in plans %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ plan.name }}</td>
    <td>£{{ plan.price_human }}</td>
    <td>
      <form method="POST" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="{{ public_key }}"
        data-image="/static/images/logo-n.png"
        data-name="Product Name"
        data-description="{{ plan.name }}"
        data-currency="{{ plan.currency }}"
        data-amount="{{ plan.price }}"
        data-locale="{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}"
        data-email="{{ user.email }}"
        data-label="{% trans 'Subscribe' %}"
        data-panel-label="{% trans 'Subscribe' %}"
        data-allow-remember-me="false"
        >
        </script>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Then I am creating the customer/subscription in response to this form being POSTed:

```
class SubscribePageView(generic.TemplateView):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    user = self.request.user
    token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
      source=token,
      plan=[[WHERE DOES THIS COME FROM??]],
      email=user.email,
    )
    user.customer_id = customer.id
    user.save()
```

But at that point I don't have the plan ID to pass back to Stripe. :/.

Am I doing this all kinds of wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the Stripe checkout script does is insert the token into a hidden field in your form, and then submit the whole form to your server. If you need any other information such as the plan, you should include that in your form too:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="{{ plan.id }}">
    <script....>
</form>
```

Now you can access the plan via `request.POST['plan']`.

Comment: But then someone could spoof the request and tell me they'd bought a different plan than the one they did buy?

Comment: But the Stripe checkout doesn't do anything to "purchase" a plan or charge a user, all it does is create a user token associated with their credit card. You still do the actual plan purchase from your server-side code, and that's the point at which you charge the user. So if they modified the post, they'd still be charged according to what you actually received.

Comment: From [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout): "It's worth noting that Checkout doesn't actually create charges—it only creates tokens. You can use those tokens to create the actual charge on your server."